# enable a button when user starts typing wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-4.0

I have 3 text boxes and a search button.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<Button Grid.Row="8" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="Search" Command="{Binding SearchPerson}" />
```

I have implemented logic where the user types something in any of the textboxes, then leaves the text box, at which point the search button gets enabled.

But, I want the search button to be enabled when a user "starts typing" (the string should not be null or whitespace) in any of the text boxes.

How do i implement this??

Many thanks in advance...

Comment: Just add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the Binding's in each `TextBox.Text`. If your logic is currently holding fine then this will now be fine as soon as you start typing

Comment: hey viv...since u posted first, do u want to post this comment as an answer...so that i accept it?

Comment: Sure, Done. Added a link to the MSDN doc's that explains this behavior to it as well that which you might want to check up on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just converting my comment to an answer.

As stated in [MSDN Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754356.aspx)

> The TextBox.Text property has a default UpdateSourceTrigger value of LostFocus.

Thus to make it "as soon as" you'd just need to explicitly switch `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the `TextBox.Text` bindings.

something like(in each `TextBox`):

```
Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [`UpdateSourceTrigger` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) on your bindings to `PropertyChanged` if you want the source to get updated as you are typing.

So change your bindings to:

```
Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
Text="{Binding Phone, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use simple TextBox->OnTextChange event:

```
button1.IsEnabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace((sender as TextBox).Text);
```